# Popup appears that warns me of the unavailability for that country

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm having some problems with this PHP script for managing a db of an elusive travel agency

Basically what I would like to do is:
check that the form fields have all been filled in, if so
then, I check the number of travel packages available for that country...
if there are any then the booking request has been completed successfully and I will reduce the packages available for that country by 1, if there are none then a popup will appear that will warn of unavailability for that country.

The problem is that when I complete the form by putting a country X as a destination, even if there are packages available for that country X, the popup appears that warns me of the unavailability for that country.

```
<?php

$msg1 = 'You have not filled in all fields!' ;
$msg2 = 'Booking request made successfully' ; 
$msg3 = 'There are no packages available for this destination';

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','book_db');

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $guests = $_POST['guests'];
    $arrivals = $_POST['arrivals'];
    $leaving = $_POST['leaving'];
 

    $request1 = "SELECT n_package FROM destination 
                 WHERE country= '$location' ";
    $res =  mysqli_query($connection, $request1);

    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) 
        || empty($address) || empty($location) || empty($guests) 
        || empty($arrivals) || empty($leaving))
    {      
        echo '<script>
                alert("'.$msg1.'");
              </script>';
    } else if($res>0) {
        //scala di 1
        $request2 = "UPDATE destination 
                        SET n_package=n_package-1 
                     WHERE country= '$location' ";
        mysqli_query($connection, $request2);
            
        echo '<script>
            alert("'.$msg2.'");
             </script>';
    }else if($res<1){
        echo '<script>
                alert("'.$msg3.'");
             </script>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'something went wrong try again';
}
?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure I have fixed up this code once before recently! Great gobs of white space do not help reading or understanding the code. Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72818008/alert-panel-does-not-appear-php

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: And the issue is exactly the same as before

Comment: `$res` is a MYSQLI::RESULT **Object** So testing it against `0` or `1` is a complete nonsense. You have to FETCH the result of that query it does not com as the resulrned value of a `mysqli_query()` Please READ [The PHP Manual pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and then the [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for example

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fetch the rows from the resultset created by a query.
2. You need to watch out for [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174)

```
<?php

$msg1 = 'You have not filled in all fields!' ;
$msg2 = 'Booking request made successfully' ; 
$msg3 = 'There are no packages available for this destination';

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','book_db');

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $guests = $_POST['guests'];
    $arrivals = $_POST['arrivals'];
    $leaving = $_POST['leaving'];
 
    $request1 = "SELECT n_package FROM destination WHERE country= ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($request1);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['location']);
    $stmt->execute($connection, $request1);
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Now `$row['n_package']` is the number of packages available. Use that in your number checks.

> In your tests though, you echo a little piece of javascript but that is ALL you echo, so that will be the complete content of the page. No `<html>` no `<head>` no `<body>` basically not a valid piece of HTML for the browser to build a page from.